# Configure Mongo using mongodb+srv

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, ubuntu

I start mongo on docker, so default host: `localhost`, port: `27017`, username: `root`
password: `example`

Now i want to connect via connection string:
`mongodb+srv://root:example@localhost/sim`
But i get an error saying:

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up
>   TXT record for host localhost

In my hosts file i have:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 _mongodb._tcp.localhost
```

Mongo is running on docker:

```
Docker ps
 mongo                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 days ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
```

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4):

In order to use the mongodb+srv scheme, you will need several DNS entries:

- Forward lookup host (A) entry for each mongod node
- TXT record for the cluster
- SRV record for the cluster

When you add `127.0.0.1 _mongodb._tcp.localhost` that is effectively a host record.

The content of the SRV record should indicate several pieces of information including port numbers and host names for the nodes providing the service.
See [RFC 2782](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782) or [SRV record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) on wikipedia.

An SRV record for a MongoDB replica set might look like:

```
_mongodb._tcp.mycluster.mydomain.com. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 mongohost1.mydomain.com.
_mongodb._tcp.mycluster.mydomain.com. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 mongohost2.mydomain.com.
_mongodb._tcp.mycluster.mydomain.com. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 mongohost3.mydomain.com.
```

The TXT record is expected to indicate URI options for the connection string, such as `"authSource=admin&replicaSet=myreplset"`.
Note that `ssl=true` is not explicitly specified, but is implied by the SRV scheme.

This [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-3-6-here-to-SRV-you-with-easier-replica-set-connections) by one of the MongoDB developers when that feature was introduced may be useful.