# Getting Error when connecting to MongoDB atlas with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a web server with the mern stack. When I try to connect to my mongodb atlas cluster with mongoose I get an error. The weird part is that I also get that error when I try to connect to my cluster with Compass. I whitelisted all IP addresses from the atlas console. I live in Colombia and chose GCP/ Sao Paulo as my region, so could that be part of the problem?

Here's my server code

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fileModel = require('./file_model.js');

let app = express();

let upload = multer();

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@psylockecluster-na7vy.gcp.mongodb.net/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:true}).catch(()=>console.log('did not connect'));
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to mongo'));
db.on('error', (e) => console.log(e));

let port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.route('/interface').get((_, res) => {
    try {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/interface.html');
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send(e.message);
    }
})

app.post('/upload', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    let fileModels = req.files.map((file) => (
        new fileModel({
            root:path.dirname(file.fieldname),
            fieldname:file.fieldname,
            originalname:file.originalname,
            encoding:file.encoding,
            mimetype:file.mimetype,
            buffer:file.buffer,
            size:file.size
        })
    ));
    let test = fileModels[0];
    test.save((err, test) => {
        console.log('uploaded file');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    res.status(200).send("Files were uploaded succesfuly");
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

And here's the error:

```
did not connect
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0-na7vy.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:202:19) {
  errno: 'ETIMEOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'cluster0-na7vy.mongodb.net'
}
```

Comment: That looks a lot like a DNS error, are you able to connect from that host using the mongo shell?

Comment: No, I am not able to do that. I can't even connect to my mongodb cluster through compass. Therefore, I think the error is not with my code, but with mongodb.

Comment: I don't think your connection is even getting to the mongodb cluster,  since the error indicates a failure to look up the required DNS record.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60388567/2282634, and use nslookup to make sure your server can resolve the SRV and TXT records for the cluster, and the A record for each node.

Comment: How do you know the error has to do with DNS? Do you mean the problem is with the domain name of the cluster? I live in Colombia by the way. Might that have to do with the  failure to look up the domain name of my cluster?